# Is it possible to provision new ec2 instances to an existing ELB?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-elb

Is it possible to add new instances to an ELB?

I'd like to not have to destroy my elb, and update my cname records w/ namecheap if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Yes of course. It would be extremely painful to scale-out your application if you couldn't do this. For a classic ELB, see the documentation [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/classic/elb-deregister-register-instances.html). For an ALB or NLB you simply register your new instance to the target group.

Comment: ah okay, the dropdown option for editing the instances was greyed out when selecting the elb.  I just had to go to the target group like you mentioned, thanks.